# Menu item behaves different on 2 different adapters

Tags: android, adapter, menuitem, android-viewholder

I have the following method which determents my menu behaviour -

```
private void showMenu(View view) {
        Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(mSongNameTv.getContext(), R.style.PopupMenu);
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view);
        forceShowIcon(popupMenu);
        String currentLoggedInUserUid = AuthProvider.getInstance().getUid();
        String videoProfileUid = mVideo.getProfile().getUid();
        boolean sameUserUploaded = StringUtils.equals(currentLoggedInUserUid, videoProfileUid);
        if (sameUserUploaded) {
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.video_holder_report_menu);
        } else {
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.video_holder_delete_menu);
        }
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.report_video:
                    onReportClicked(view);
                    return true;
                case R.id.delete_video:
                    onDeleteVideoClicked();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }
```

I have 2 adapters that create this ViewHolder on OnCreateViewHolder() method - on one of them it behaves as it should - compares UID's from the video and the user and inflates the menu accordingly. On the other adapter, not only that it works the opposite way (it shows the menu that it should NOT show) but I can't even debug it because when putting the debugger on OnCreateViewHolder on that adapter it does not trigger the debugger for some reason, though it is for sure that same ViewHolder.

More on that, when putting a debugger on this method it does not trigger at all the debugger when checking the "problematic" adapter, but it sure does on the other one. And after inflating the wrong menu item it does not perform it's OnClick method it should perform.

What could have caused the logic to switch when working with a different adapter? and why can't I debug it at all at one of the adapters?

Comment: Are you really sure that you're actually using that other, problematic `Adapter`? I mean, did you possibly copy/paste some code, and forget to change the `Adapter` class?

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 different adapters, check the XML to see who inflates it.